# sparkR Installation Issue with spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6

Tags: sparkr

After installing spark it got installed successfully but
while running sparkR i am getting issue as env: R: Permission denied??
my spark shell is working. can someone help me out with this issue???

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: Might be you are not a root user.